# How much data/networking usage does an Oracle Client use while running queries across schemas?

Tags: oracle, azure

When I run a query to copy data from schemas, does it perform all SQL on the server end or copy data to a local application and then push it back out to the DB?

The two tables sit in the same DB, but the DB is accessed through a VPN. Would it change if it was across databases?

For instance (Running in Toad Data Point):

```
create table schema2.table
  as  
select 
  sum(row1)
 ,row2
from schema1
```

The purpose I ask the question is because I'm getting quotes for a Virtual Machine in Azure Cloud and want to make sure that I'm not going to break the bank on data costs.

Comment: If if were across databases, you would need a database link from one database to another. Data would be copied over the link. A local application doesn't participate in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing of SQL statements on the same database usually takes place entirely on the server and generates little network traffic.

In Oracle, schemas are a logical object.  There is no physical barrier between them.  In a SQL query using two tables it makes no difference if those tables are in the same schema or in different schemas (other than privilege issues).

Some exceptions:

1. **Real Application Clusters (RAC) -** RAC may share a huge amount of data between the nodes.  For example, if the table was cached on one node and the processing happened on another, it could send all the table data through the network.  (I'm not sure how this works on the cloud though.  Normally the inter-node traffic is done with a separate, dedicated network connection.)
2. **Database links -** It should be obvious if your application is using database links though.
3. **Oracle Reports and Forms(?) -** A few rare tools have client-side PL/SQL processing.  Possibly those programs might send data to the client for processing.  But I still doubt it would do something crazy like send an entire table to the client to be sorted, and then return the results to the server.
4. **Backups/archive logs -** I assume all the data will be backed up.  I'm not sure how that's counted, but possibly that means all data written will also be counted as network traffic eventually.

The queries below are examples of different ways to check the network traffic being generated.

```
--SQL*Net bytes sent for a session.
select *
from gv$sesstat
join v$statname
    on gv$sesstat.statistic# = v$statname.statistic#
--You probably also want to filter for a specific INST_ID and SID here.
where lower(display_name) like '%sql*net%';

--SQL*Net bytes sent for the entire system.
select *
from gv$sysstat
where lower(name) like '%sql*net%'
order by value desc;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the detailed explanation!